# Use external power supply

Tags: power, usb-power, pi-pico

I'm a newbie

I have a circuit which requires 12v to drive some ESCs that go to brushless motors and  5V that goes to pin 39 of a raspberry pi pico,  they share a neutral / negative to complete the circuit.

I would also like to see the std out from the pico to help understand how my program is behaving by connecting it to my ubuntu linux computer.

My question is how do I do this, if I plug the micro usb into the pico then it will try and get the power from that source. But I really want to power the pico through 5v to pin 39.

Is there some way to specify that the power should come from pin 39 and that the micro usb should just be used to transfer data and view the std out of the pico?

This is the kind of schema I'm talking about but a pico instead of an esp32

[Rough Schema Image](https://www.enbuenosaires.com/images/electronics-schema-4.png)

Comment: Perhaps make up a USB cable without the power pin connected.

Comment: Have you read the Pico documentation and/or studied the schematic? AFAIK there is a diode isolating power inputs. It has been years since I read this and have not used alternative power.